# How to see e-commerce data in Firebase Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, firebase

I'm currently in the process of setting up Firebase Analytics for my apps on iOS and Android. I already have an "old" Google Analytics property that allows me to see all the basic things that Firebase also support in one way or another.

But I also use the old GA to see detailed e-commerce information about sales, especially Product Performance. Unless there is something fundamental about Firebase that I am missing completely, there seems to be no similar feature out-of-the-box?

It appears that I can only see aggregated revenue for all sales and not revenue on a product level. I guess I could do that by setting up events for individual product purchases, but what if I have more products than the maximum number of events allowed in Firebase?

So my question is really: how can I set up Firebase to show me all the basic "Conversions"-things from GA like product revenue, quantity and unique puchases?